# I am not able to set background image in ionic3

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I am trying to set background image in ionic 3. I put my image under sssest-image folder and I am getting an error:

**Error**

> GET http://localhost:8100/image/Static-Line-Jump-in-the-sky.jpg 404
>   (Not Found)

**Code**

```
 body
    {
        background-image: url('../../assest/image/Static-Line-Jump-in-the-sky.jpg');
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

sorry i got the solution 
just give id to your tag ion-content anf then always set a parth through assest/image folder like this

```
#welcome
{
    background-image: url('../assets/image/Static-Line-Jump-in-the-sky.jpg');
}
```